# Dartz - get left of Either

Tags: dart, functional-programming, dartz

```
var newRight;
if(either.isRight()) {
  newRight = either.getOrElse(() => throw UnimplementedError());
} else {
  return Left(either.fold((f) => f, (r) => throw UnimplementedError()))
}
```

How can I get left side of either and return it as in the example above? Any other, maybe cleaner solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `swap()`. It swaps the `Left` and `Right` part of an `Either`

`either.swap().getOrElse(() => throw UnimplementedError());`

or you can use fold if you can reduce left and right to same type.

`myEither.fold(fToApplyLeft, gToApplyRight)`

Comment: I cannot reduce left and right to the same type. For now I went for fold `return Left(either.fold(
          (f) => f, (r) => throw UnimplementedError()));`. I hoped to achieve cleaner solution, but swap seems to be similarly messy. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.